# If $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable show that $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is measurable when $f(x) \neq 0$

Tags: measure-theory

If $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and

$
   g(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{1}{f(x)} & : f(x)\neq 0\\
       0 & : f(x)=0
     \end{array}
   \right.
$

Prove that $g(x)$ is measurable.

I'm am quite new to measure theory and have been trying to solve this problem for quite some time now.

So far I have tried to show $g^{-1}([-\infty,c)) \in \mathcal{A}$ and

I get that $(\frac{1}{f(x)})^{-1}=f^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})$ but I am at a loss for how to break up the inverse of $g([-\infty,c)$ into parts to show that each part is in $\mathcal{A}$ any hints or suggestions would be great. I'm not asking for a solution, just a little bit of guidance towards the solution.

Comment: Here's a hint that might get you started. Let's assume $f(x)$ is always positive, so that $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ always. For $c$ positive, $g(x) < c$ if and only if $f(x) > \frac{1}{c}$. So what is $g^{-1}([-\infty, c))$ in terms of $f^{-1}$ of something? Now fill in some details to consider the general case when $f(x)$ and $c$ may not be positive.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, just to check, would it then be correct to say that $g^{-1}([-\infty, c))=\{x \in X | g(x) < c)\}=\{x \in X | f(x) > \frac{1}{c}\} = f^{-1}((\frac{1}{c},\infty])$?

Comment: that is of course when f(x) is positive.

Comment: That's correct, when $f$ and $c$ are both positive. For the general case, you may have to write $g^{-1}([-\infty, c))$ as a union of sets, as Alex suggests in his answer below.

Comment: Am I right in saying $g^{-1}(0) = \{ x \in X | f(x) = 0\} = f^{-1}(0)$ since $g(x) = 0 \iff f(x) = 0$? and then partition $[-\infty,c)$ according to whether $c <0, c = 0, c > 0$?

Comment: Your first statement is correct (in this problem, $f$ takes only finite real number values, right?). And yes, I think you have the idea in your second question.

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me if it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Can you express $g^{-1}([\infty,c))$ as (a union of) sets of the form $f^{-1}(E)$, where $E \in \mathcal{A}$?

Answer (score 1):

for $c \in \mathbb{R}$

$ g^{-1}([-\infty,c)) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       f^{-1}((\frac{1}{c},\infty]) & :c < 0\\
       f^{-1}([-\infty,0])& : c = 0 \\
f^{-1}([-\infty,0] \cup (\frac{1}{c},\infty]) &: c > 0\\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

In each of those cases, since $f$ is measurable, $f^{-1} \in \mathcal{A}$ thus $g$ is measurable. Is this correct?

Comment: Check the $c<0$ case again.

Comment: for $c < 0$ you get that $\frac{1}{f(x)} < c$, but now $c < 0 \implies f(x) < 0$ so $ 1 > c.f(x)$ and again, $f(x) > \frac{1}{c}$

Comment: but, I'm not sure that you can do this?

Comment: Of course you can!

Comment: so it's right then?

Comment: $f(x) > \frac{1}{c}$, _and_, as you stated, $f(x) < 0$.